# how to append text to an input field on click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have an image and everytime you click on it I want to append the `name` (or `id`) of the image  into an input field and then submit it (automatically if possible).

```
<?php

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jstophp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a><img id="rar" src="images/5euro.jpg"></a> <br />
<a><img id="rar2" src="images/5euro.jpg"></a> <br />


<form action="form2.php" method="post">
    Name: <label><input id="inputF" type="text" name="name"></label><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

this is form2.php:

```
<?php

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "this is the name ". $_POST['name']
?>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the javascript:

```
var check = null;
var x = $('#inputF');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){

        //gets attribute id from image
        check = $(this).attr("id");

        //puts image name into input field value (doesnt work)
        x.val(x.val() + check);

        //checks variable `check`
        console.log(check);
    });
});
```

When I print into the console `check` prints normally but when I actually submit the form it doesn't work.

Comment: *'it doesn't work'* - **How** doesn't it work? What is your desired result?

Comment: For me it is working. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/KkAZP/

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y62xu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $('img').click(function(){

    $('#inputF').val($('#inputF').val() +","+ this.id)

    $("input[type=submit]").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. The only thing that's missing is that I would like it to submit automatically after you click the image.

Answer (score 0):

Script is working fine. Include your img tag inside form tag like below.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jstophp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="form2.php" method="post">
<a><img id="rar" src="images/5euro.jpg"></a> <br />
<a><img id="rar2" src="images/5euro.jpg"></a> <br />
    Name: <label><input id="inputF" type="text" name="name"></label><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the assignment of x into the click function like this:

```
var check = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){

        var x = $('#inputF');

        //gets attribute id from image
        check = $(this).attr("id");

        //puts image name into input field value (doesnt work)
        x.val(x.val() + check);

        //checks variable `check`
        console.log(check);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('img').click(function(){
   var test=$(this).attr("src");
   $('#inputF').val($('#inputF').val() +","+test)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is jsfiddle for that - http://jsfiddle.net/DKL79/

and code:

```
var $form = $('#formF');
var $input = $('#inputF', $form);

$('img').on('click', function(e) {
    $input.val(this.id);
    $form.submit();
});
```